# Matrix Traversal in C/C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

I am trying to solve this problem:

Given a 2d grid map of '1's (land) and '0's (water), count the number of islands. An island is surrounded by water and is formed by connecting adjacent lands horizontally or vertically. You may assume all four edges of the grid are all surrounded by water.

Example 1:

```
11110
11010
11000
00000
```

My solution is:

```
  #include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#define N 5
#define M 4

using namespace std;

int a[5][4] = 
{
    1,1,1,1,0,
    1,1,0,1,0,
    1,1,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0
};

int counter = 0;


void dfs(int i, int j)
{
    a[i][j] = 0 ;
    if (i - 1 >= 0) dfs(i - 1, j);
    if (i + 1<M) dfs(i + 1, j);
    if (j - 1 >= 0) dfs(i, j - 1);
    if (j + 1<N) dfs(i, j + 1);
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (a[i][j] != 0) {
                dfs(i, j);
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout <<"No. Of Islands: "<<counter<< endl;
}
```

**This solution shows exception in Visua Studio. I can't see where it goes wrong while calling the dfs function.**

Comment: There is no question.

Comment: `a[5][4]` --> `a[4][5]` ? also `i < M.. j<N` (M:10, N:10)??

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Could you plz explain a bit. I am dead confused .

Comment: This code won't do what you expect it to anyhow, counter will always equal `M*N` at the end.

Comment: @adrian008 `a[i][j]` out of bounds

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Where is it going out of bound, I put all the cjhecks ?

Comment: @adrian008 You declared a 5 x 4 matrix, and then assume it is 10 x 10.  It really wasn't that hard to spot.  You are overrunning the boundaries of your array in the loop.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am sorry for that I posted an earlier code even with correct boundaries it is throwing error. I will correct that. Th code in the edit is the same with corrected boundaries and it is the same behaviour,

Comment: @adrian008 Well, your `dfs` function does not check bounds.  You are calling dfs with `i` and/or `j` potentially equal to 10, which is out of bounds (assuming your matrix is 10 x 10)..  Why not put a simple `cout << i << " " << j << "\n";` on the fist line of `dfs` to see what the indices are that are coming in?  In general, why are you not debugging?

Comment: @adrian008 `This solution shows exception in Visua Studio.`  You should have posted what the exception was.  The exception is due to stack overflow, meaning that your `dfs` function repeatedly calls itself without returning.

Comment: No ending condition to the recursive dfs function. See my answer below. Everything else is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an ending condition to the dfs function. Add this line in the beginning of the function:

```
if (a[i][j]==0) return;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line

```
cout <<"No. Of Islands: "+counter<< endl;
```

`"No. Of Islands: "` is a string literal. Adding `counter` to it, is adding an offset to a `const char *`, which is not what you want. Also, if `counter` is large enough (which it is), it will try to read out of bounds. It needs to be

```
cout <<"No. Of Islands: " << counter << endl;
```

This will stream `counter` to `cout` which will understand it as an `int` and output it as such.